# How can I convert the searchParams function into an object? URLSearchParams { 'title' => '1' } to { title : 1 }

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

I want to convert the searchParams function into an object? like this =>>> 
URLSearchParams { 'title' => '1' } to { title : 1 }

I want this to be done for everything in the URLSearchParams, not just one value

i get and push to object like this

```
 const url = { title: "" };  
 url.title=req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("title");
```

but i want for any value

Comment: What do you mean by "not just one value" / "but i want for any value"

Comment: If you just want to convert the URLSearchParams object to a plain object you can use `const obj = Object.fromEntries(req.nextUrl.searchParams)`, but it's not clear why you want to do that, you can access multiple values from `nextUrl.searchParams` as well.

Comment: An object can only store one value at each key, but an instance of `URLSearchParams` can hold [multiple](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/getAll), so converting one to an object can potentially cause a loss of values. There is purpose to different data structures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a trivial way to do this, but one could write a function pretty easily to convert a `URLSearchParams` object to a standard object:

```js
function paramsToObject(searchParams) {
    let obj = {};
    for (const [key, value] of searchParams.entries()) {
        obj[key] = value;
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Comment: If we give req.nextUrl.searchParams as its input, we can convert it into an object, and this answer is correct

Answer (score 2):

I think the most straight-forward way would be this:

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
searchParams.set( 'title', 'blub' );

const obj = Object.fromEntries( searchParams.entries() );
```

Comment: I don't want to add a value to searchParams and I want to convert all its values ​​into objects